# Can I specify a name for the index which SQL Server creates for my unique constraint?

Tags: sql-server, index, constraint, ddl

In SQL Server I deploy a table with a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Something] (
    [IdentityId]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()
    -- Whatever else...
)
```

and this makes SQL Server to create a unique index to back the constraint. That index will have name generated automatically and looking something like

```
UQ__tmp_ms_x__1F778345BD
```

where `UQ` means "unique" and all the rest is well, random stuff to me. If I have two unique constraints for the same table they just look like two random strings which is not very convenient.

Is it possible to specify the name for the index which is created under the hood when a unique constraint is created?

Answer (score 7):

Referencing the documentation for [Create Unique Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints), you should be able to use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Something](
    [IdentityId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [MyUniqueConstraintName] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [IdentityId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```